# Set height of two views same in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have two views in different part of layout, not beside or in row, I want to make height of one equal to another, how can I do this in ConstraintLayout? There is similar feature in iOS Autolayout, there should be something similar in Android.

[image]

Comment: Not that your question is unreasonable, but why do you need to be able to do this? Is the red view's height not known ahead of time? Anyway, I don't think you can do this with `ConstraintLayout`; you'll probably have to use Java to do it.

Comment: No the height is not known, it's text is dynamic and may be multiline.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one this should be help for u

```
txt_red.setText("It's text is dynamic and may be multiline");
txt_blue.setText("It my suggestion for u both view dynamic text set after view.getHeight()");



int red_height = getViewHeight(txt_red);
int blue_height = getViewHeight(txt_blue);
```

Get view height use this method

```
private int getViewHeight(TextView txt) {
    TextPaint myTextPaint = new TextPaint();
    myTextPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    myTextPaint.setTextSize(16 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    myTextPaint.setColor(0xFF000000);

    int width = 200;
    Layout.Alignment alignment = Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL;
    float spacingMultiplier = 1;
    float spacingAddition = 0;
    boolean includePadding = false;

    StaticLayout myStaticLayout = new StaticLayout(txt.getText(), myTextPaint, width, alignment, spacingMultiplier, spacingAddition, includePadding);
    int height = myStaticLayout.getHeight();
    return height;
}
```

After compare two view height larger view height set as both view then look same height of it.

Answer (score -1):

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/red"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
/>

<View
    android:id="@+id/blue"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/red"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/red"
/>
```

Constraint layout does't have width and height constraint, you need to use `layout_constraintStart_toStartOf` and `layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf` together to achieve equal height.

The available attributes are:

```
layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf
layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf
layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf
layout_constraintRight_toRightOf
layout_constraintTop_toTopOf
layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf
layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf
layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf
layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf
layout_constraintStart_toEndOf
layout_constraintStart_toStartOf
layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf
layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf
```

To control the positioning you need to use:

```
android:layout_marginStart
android:layout_marginEnd
android:layout_marginLeft
android:layout_marginTop
android:layout_marginRight
android:layout_marginBottom
```

Comment: But this will move blue button and set it's top same as red's. I want to keep red button on top left and blue button on bottom right.

Comment: To control the positioning, you might need to use margins

Comment: How can I set a margin equal to height of another control?

Comment: From my understanding, you can't.

Comment: You might use Guideline instead to constraint your layout.